# Migration options

Tags: discussion, feature-request, migration

When I click the off-topic choice because I think a question belongs on another exchange, my only choice is meta.health. What about Biology, Psychology, Fitness, etc? What does it take to get those added to the list of options?

Comment: Lang's answer is correct. If you think it is suitable for another site, simply flag it for a moderator's attention. If it is suitable, we can migrate it. If we are uncertain if it is a good fit, we can ask the mods on the destination site.

Comment: I guess ([meta-tag:migration]) tag would be suitable for this question. (I do not have sufficient reputation to edit on meta - which is why I am posting the suggestion in a comment. Adding suitable tags might help to find past discussions more quickly if a similar topic surfaces again in the future.)

Answer (score 10):

As I understand the policies, [it takes for us to get out of beta:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296832/what-are-the-limitations-in-beta)

> Beta sites don't have default migration paths (although moderators can still migrate to/from)

and for the [target sites to be out of beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258593/do-the-new-graduation-policies-have-any-effect-on-migrations-to-beta-sites) as well?

That means except for things really belonging here on HealthMeta the option "belongs on another site" is useless and will remain so for a while.

The workaround is to vote to close with a custom reason, stating the presumed target site in the comment and optionally flag the question for moderator attention.

Comment: I was afraid this was the answer.

Comment: Definitely not user-friendly.